# Rendering units in MathJaX

Tags: support

How does one go about rendering units properly in MathJaX?

For example,

$$
100 N.m,\ \  3 \times 10^8 m.s^{-1}
$$

It's conventional to typeset units in upright (non-italic) font, as in:

$$
100 \textrm{ N.m},\ \  3 \times 10^8 \textrm{m}.\textrm{s}^{-1}
$$

In LaTeX, you might import `units` `siunits` or `siunitx` for this, but those packages don't exit in MathJax.

You can kind-of do it using `\textrm{}` but this doesn't play nice with superscripts. For example `9.81 \textrm{m.s^{-2}}` comes out as

$$
9.81 \textrm{m.s^{-2}}
$$

which is not quite as desired.

Comment: Is this what you mean: \$\mathrm{m.s^{-2}}\$ `\$\mathrm{m.s^{-2}}\$`

Comment: @jippie: Yes, that does the trick. D'oh.

Comment: related: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-to-write-physical-units/3287#3287

Answer (score 2):

I can never remember the URL for [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so I google for "mathjax stackexchange".

I should maybe add a bookmark.

> Fonts
>   Use `\mathrm` for roman font